# how to display popup in web mapping application

Tags: javascript, html, css, openlayers

I want to display the data in the shape file on the click event in my web mapping application. I added the popup functionality for the same. but I am not able to find the error. I have published files using Geoserver. please can you tell me how can i achieve this?
this is my code-

index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>WMS Layer Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 565px;
    }

    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    #background-map {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    #dropdown-container1 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 25px;
      right: 20px;
    }

    #dropdown-container2 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 45px;
      right: 20px;
    }

    #logout-button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 1px;
      right: 20px; /* Adjust the right distance to position the button as needed */
      z-index: 1; /* Ensure the button is above the map */
    }

    .ol-popup {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        bottom: 12px;
        left: -50px;
        min-width: 280px;
      }
      .ol-popup:after, .ol-popup:before {
        top: 100%;
        border: solid transparent;
        content: " ";
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
      }
      .ol-popup:after {
        border-top-color: white;
        border-width: 10px;
        left: 48px;
        margin-left: -10px;
      }
      .ol-popup:before {
        border-top-color: #cccccc;
        border-width: 11px;
        left: 48px;
        margin-left: -11px;
      }
      .ol-popup-closer {
        text-decoration: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        right: 8px;
      }
      .ol-popup-closer:after {
        content: "✖";
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map-container">
    <button id="logout-button">Logout</button>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
      <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
      <div id="popup-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="dropdown-container2">
      <label><b>Background Map:</label>
      <select id="background-map-dropdown">
        <option value="OSMStandard">OSM Standard</option>
        <option value="OSMHumanitarian">OSM Humanitarian</option>
        <option value="CartoDarkAll">Carto Dark All</option>
        <option value="StamenTerrainWithLabels">Stamen Terrain With Labels</option>
        <option value="StamenTerrain">Stamen Terrain (will take some time)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="dropdown-container1">
      <label for="wms-layer-dropdown">Select Layer:</label>
      <select id="wms-layer-dropdown">
        <option value="Aaryaman_Samode">All layers</option>
        <option value="SAMODE_GUT_BOUNDARY">SAMODE GUT BOUNDARY</option>
        <option value="STRUCTURES">Structures</option>
        <option value="Tree_Point">Tree_Point</option>
        <option value="ELECTRIC_POLES">Light Poles</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js-
"

```
// Create a new view for the map with a specified center, zoom level, and projection
var view = new ol.View({
  center: [8254682.451123528, 2388403.8093110425],
  zoom: 13.50,
  rotation: 0.5,
  projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

// Create a new map instance with the specified view and target HTML element
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: view
});

// Create a source for the WMS layer with the URL and layer parameters
var treePointWMSSource = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Aaryaman/wms',
  params: {
    'LAYERS': 'Aaryaman:Tree_Point'
  },
  serverType: 'geoserver'
});

// Create a WMS layer using the previously defined source
var treePointWMSLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: treePointWMSSource
});

// Base Layers
const openstreetMapStandard = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM(),
  visible: true, // Initially, set this to false
  title: 'OSMStandard'
});

const openstreetMapHumanitarian = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM({
    url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
  }),
  visible: false, // Initially, set this to false
  title: 'OSMHumanitarian'
});

const cartoDBBaseLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'http://{1-4}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    attributions: '© CARTO'
  }),
  visible: false, // Initially, set this to false
  title: 'CartoDarkAll'
});

 // Stamen basemap layer
 const StamenTerrainWithLabels = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.Stamen({
    layer: 'terrain-labels',
  }),
  visible: false,
  title: 'StamenTerrainWithLabels'
})

const StamenTerrain = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg',
  }),
  visible: false,
  title: 'StamenTerrain'
})

// Add the base layers to the map
map.addLayer(openstreetMapStandard);
map.addLayer(openstreetMapHumanitarian);
map.addLayer(cartoDBBaseLayer);
map.addLayer(StamenTerrain);
map.addLayer(StamenTerrainWithLabels);

// Function to update the background map based on the selected option
function updateBackgroundMap(selectedBackgroundMap) {
  // Hide all base layers by default
  openstreetMapStandard.setVisible(false);
  openstreetMapHumanitarian.setVisible(false);
  cartoDBBaseLayer.setVisible(false);
  StamenTerrain.setVisible(false);
  StamenTerrainWithLabels.setVisible(false);

  // Show the selected base layer based on the value
  switch (selectedBackgroundMap) {
    case 'OSMStandard':
      openstreetMapStandard.setVisible(true);
      break;
    case 'OSMHumanitarian':
      openstreetMapHumanitarian.setVisible(true);
      break;
    case 'CartoDarkAll':
      cartoDBBaseLayer.setVisible(true);
      break;
    case "StamenTerrain":
      StamenTerrain.setVisible(true);
      break;
    case "StamenTerrainWithLabels":
      StamenTerrainWithLabels.setVisible(true);
      break;
    default:
      // You can set a default base layer to be shown here if needed
  }
}

// Get the dropdown element for selecting background maps
var backgroundMapDropdown = document.getElementById('background-map-dropdown');

// Add a change event listener to the dropdown to update the selected background map
backgroundMapDropdown.addEventListener('change', function () {
  var selectedBackgroundMap = backgroundMapDropdown.value;
  updateBackgroundMap(selectedBackgroundMap);
});

// Get the dropdown element for selecting WMS layers
var dropdown = document.getElementById('wms-layer-dropdown');

// Add a change event listener to the dropdown to update the selected WMS layer
dropdown.addEventListener('change', function () {
  var selectedLayer = dropdown.value;
  // Update the WMS layer parameters with the selected layer
  treePointWMSSource.updateParams({ 'LAYERS': 'Aaryaman:' + selectedLayer });
  // Make the WMS layer visible
  treePointWMSLayer.setVisible(true);
});

// Create a scale line control
var scaleControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine({
  units: 'metric', // Use metric units (kilometers and meters)
  bar: true, // Display a scale bar
  steps: 4, // Number of scale bar steps
  text: true, // Display text (e.g., "1 km" or "500 m")
  minWidth: 100, // Minimum width for the scale control
});

// Add the scale control to the map
map.addControl(scaleControl);

// Add the WMS layer to the map (added after the base layers)
map.addLayer(treePointWMSLayer);

// Add a single-click event listener to the map for feature information retrieval (as in your code)
map.on('singleclick', function (event) {
  var clickedCoordinate = event.coordinate;
  // Get the GetFeatureInfo URL for the clicked coordinate and resolution
  var url = treePointWMSSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
    clickedCoordinate,
    view.getResolution(),
    view.getProjection(),
    { 'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json' }
  );

  // Use jQuery to make an AJAX request to fetch feature information
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      // Process and display the fetched feature information
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.log('Error fetching feature info:', error);
    }
  });
});

// Function to display the feature information in a popup
function displayFeatureInfo(feature, coordinate) {
  // Clear the popup content
  var popupContent = document.getElementById('popup-content');
  popupContent.innerHTML = '';

  // Check if there are features available
  if (feature && feature.length > 0) {
    // Loop through each feature
    for (var i = 0; i < feature.length; i++) {
      // Get the properties of the feature
      var properties = feature[i].getProperties();

      // Create a div element to display feature information
      var featureDiv = document.createElement('div');

      // Iterate through the properties and display them
      for (var key in properties) {
        if (properties.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          var value = properties[key];
          // Exclude some properties if needed
          if (key !== 'geometry' && key !== 'boundedBy') {
            var propertyDiv = document.createElement('div');
            propertyDiv.innerHTML = '<b>' + key + ':</b> ' + value;
            featureDiv.appendChild(propertyDiv);
          }
        }
      }

      // Add the feature div to the popup content
      popupContent.appendChild(featureDiv);
    }

    // Set the popup's position
    var popup = new ol.Overlay({
      element: document.getElementById('popup'),
      positioning: 'bottom-center',
      stopEvent: false,
      offset: [0, -30],
    });
    map.addOverlay(popup);
    popup.setPosition(coordinate);
  } else {
    // No features found, hide the popup
    var popup = new ol.Overlay({
      element: document.getElementById('popup'),
      positioning: 'bottom-center',
      stopEvent: false,
      offset: [0, -30],
    });
    map.addOverlay(popup);
    popup.setPosition(undefined);
  }
}

// Add the single-click event listener to the map for feature information retrieval
map.on('singleclick', function (event) {
  var clickedCoordinate = event.coordinate;
  // Get the GetFeatureInfo URL for the clicked coordinate and resolution
  var url = treePointWMSSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
    clickedCoordinate,
    32643, // Set the desired resolution here
    view.getProjection(),
    { 'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json' }
  );

  // Use jQuery to make an AJAX request to fetch feature information
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      // Process and display the fetched feature information
      displayFeatureInfo(data.features, clickedCoordinate);
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.log('Error fetching feature info:', error);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You do nothing with the requested data: // Process and display the fetched feature information